# reducer state array of objects is showing new added item but removed automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am inserting into database by insertion query. The value is successfully added. I take the last entered value and throw it to the `redux state`. I have used `componentWillReceiveProps`.

I wonder why it removed as already added. In the following image, I have an `array` of `16 items` and I added a new 17th item. Hence, it shown that it is removed at the end.[image: bug report image]

```
dispatch(allCatSessions('allCategorySessions', sessions))

componentWillReceiveProps (nextprops) {
    if (nextprops && nextprops.filters && nextprops.filters.allCategorySessions) {
      console.log('State in compoene witll receive:', {catAllSessions: nextprops.filters.allCategorySessions})
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong it should be `nextProps` not `nextprops` , also if you're on the latest version of react , you should use `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()` though `componentWillReceiveProps()` and its new alias is going to be deprecated in v.17